# How can I use my free allowance on Heroku?

Tags: heroku, hubot

I have been playing around creating 'Hubot' a bot for HipChat. I deployed it to Heroku, and have been using the free dyno.

I don't have much experience with Heroku, but on the pricing page it says 'Must sleep 6 hours in a 24 hour period'. Is that forced, or can I go over the limit? It also says 'Sleeps after 30 mins of inactivity'.

Is that why Hubot comes with a 'keep alive url', to prevent inactivity, therefore causing me to be charged?

I am only experimenting, and don't want to accidentally start getting billed for using the service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the free Heroku dynos, then yes -- the 6 hours of sleep will be 'forced' every day. You don't need to worry about getting charged for keeping your dyno awake, Heroku will just put it to sleep for you.

Comment: What does `"must sleep 6 hours in a 24 hour period"` mean?  Does it mean the app won't be available for a continuous six-hour period in a day?

Comment: It means that the app will be 'not currently up' for at least 6 hours per day. If your dyno isn't used frequently, it will 'go to sleep' until it is requested by a user. In the event this happens, the clock starts ticking towards the 6 hour quota. It doesn't need to be for 6 continuous hours per day.